# Expected Value of $\frac{1}{\hat{p}}$

Tags: expected-value, proportion

Given a sample proportion $\hat{p} = \frac{X}{n}$, how can one easily find E[$\frac{1}{\hat{p}}$]?

Clearly E[$\frac{1}{\hat{p}}$] $\neq $ $\frac{1}{E[\hat{p}]}$

Jensen's inequality says E[$\frac{1}{\hat{p}}$] $\geq$ $\frac{1}{E[\hat{p}]}$

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: is $P(X=0) > 0$?

Comment: First of all, $\hat{p}$ is a random variable because it is a function of the $X$ which are random, if I understand what you're getting at. If you know the distribution of $X$, say, $Bern(p)$, then the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) should help you here.

Comment: By considering $E[1/\hat p - 1] = E[1/\hat p]-1$ and replacing $p$ by the complementary proportion $1-p$, your question becomes identical to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302970.

Comment: @whuber That's an interesting approach that makes the math a lot simpler. Thanks!